# what is a down level windows server?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012

In the following context. You can not add roles and features in Windows Server manager to install roles and features on down level servers?

Reading a Windows Server 2012 book but the way .

Comment: Down level servers as in Server 2003 and 8?

Comment: Can not propagate permissions and features to slave servers?

Comment: Think your Correct Ben it is servers with older operating em systems. Thanks

Comment: @topcat - Please clarify your question by editing it.  I am pretty sure there is an option to export the roles that can be migrated to previous versions, and if there isn't by default, then there are tools that exist that allow this.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we only use servers that run Windows.

A downlevel server is an older Windows Server version in your network. Mind you, I'm not talking about release versions. I'm talking about versions like Windows Server 2003 or Windows Server 2008 R2 or Windows Server 2016 or Windows Server 2019.

EXAMPLE:
You have a network of servers that run the Operating System (OS) Windows 2016 and Windows Server 2019. In this particular example, the servers that run the Windows Server 2016, are the down-level servers.